# Eclipse RCP, how to determine start of a token by RuleBasedTokenScanner

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

i'm trying to implement a editor on RCP. Currently, i meet a problem, i'd like to highlight some keywords, but in my implementation, those keywords will be highlight event them are part of other normal words actually. I suppose the reason is that the scanner scans token from current first character and regardless of the before one. How could i fix it, could you please help? Thanks.[image]

Comment: See [Incorrect partition detected by PartitionScanner in custom TextEditor for eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5699642).

Comment: I've fixed it last year ; ). Thanks anyway!

Comment: Cool. If you did anything beyond what's mentioned in other post, you might want to publicly answer your own question. Other people will probably have the same issue and end up looking here.